# Game programming - CPU usage of an infinite loop

Tags: java, software-design, 2d-games

I want to create a simple 2D game. I don't want to use threads. The programming language will be Java (but could be any language, does not really matter...).

Is it possible to avoid high CPU usage if I use a main loop like `while(true)...` (infinite loop)?

Comment: Please expand your question with more details and specifics. This is unanswerable as of now...

Comment: What language is the game to be written in? If you're using JavaScript or ActionScript an infinite loop will kill your game. If you're using XNA (C#) then there is a game loop already provided.

Comment: I haven't found a good book on the history of 2D game development, but you might be interested in the "classic game postmortems" on the Game Developers' Conference vault:
http://www.gdcvault.com/free/category

The creators of many old games explain their process in those lectures.

Comment: now that you have stated that it would be written in java: are you planning to use swing to draw the game?

Comment: twall: yes, I am using Swing. Do you think Swing is good for Java games?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a game you typically have a main loop that runs everything.  However, in order to avoid doing unnecessary things, it is typical to only update the game at a certain frame-rate (such as 60 Frames Per Second (FPS)).

Most games accomplish this by causing the CPU to sleep until a new frame needs to be calculated/drawn.  In the python game library, pygame, this is done using [pygame.time.wait](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.wait):

> Will pause for a given number of milliseconds. This function sleeps the process to share the processor with other programs. A program that waits for even a few milliseconds will consume very little processor time.

Comment: This answer was written when the question was language agnostic.  There are equivalents for most other languages, including Java.

Comment: Yes, I was not going to include language in the question because I know almost all languages have this kind of resources. +1

Comment: @tecnotron Do you have a language preference or is your question intended to be extremely generalised? If the latter, this is the closest you're going to get to an answer.

Comment: It is a generic question. The programming language does not really matter.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate Darthfett's answer, the main loop for a console game would typically look something like:

```
#define FRAMELENGTH (1.0 / 60.0) // 60hz = 16.6ms per NTSC frame. Different for PAL. 
while ( !QuitSignalled() ) 
{
   double frameStartTime = GetTime(); // imagine microsecond precision
   HandleUserInput( PollController() );
   SimulateEntities(); 
   Physics();
   Render();
   Sound();
   etc();

   double timeUntilNextFrameShouldStart = GetTime() - frameStartTime + FRAMELENGTH;
   sleep( timeUntilNextFrameShouldStart  );   
}
// if down here, we got the 'quit' signal 
ExitToDesktop();
```

Of course the loop above will break if a frame ever takes more than 16.6ms to execute, so we have special code to detect that and catch up or drop frames, but that's the basic idea. Also, until recently we didn't actually use floating-point numbers for time, but fixed-point microsecond counters.

Comment: I know this is a several-year-old answer. I think your `timeUntilNextFrameShouldStart` is calculated wrong, it should be "how much time each frame has, minus how much time this whole frame took", so you sleep for the remainder, **if it's positive**: `timeUntilNextFrameShouldStart = FRAMELENGTH - (GetTime() - frameStartTime); if (timeUntilNextFrameShouldStart > 0.0) {sleep(timeUntilNextFrameShouldStart);}`

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is "block on input" ... and you get *zero* CPU usage. Until something happens, anyway.

Just about any sockets program will have a loop something like this:

```
  while (true) {
    select ()
    ...
```

You could just as easily wait on a "`getchar()`", or "`WaitOnSingleEvent()`"

One could argue that "block on I/O" is actually an *optimal* design strategy.  It beats the heck out of the alternative - "polling" (Polling is Evil).

IMHO..

Comment: Blocking on I/O isn't a popular model in games because you need the rendering to run at a constant 60hz regardless of whether input comes in or not. If the main loop waits for I/O, then you can get into a situation where your frames have different timesteps (so you can't run simulation/AI/physics/sound with a constant Δt) or worse, have the rendering stall for a long time waiting for a keypress.

Typically in games polling on I/O is exactly what we do -- the game runs 60 frames per second no matter what, and each frame we look at the controller. Sometimes more than once per frame.

Comment: If I "block on input" will the loop be waiting for user input? So how will the animation continue to run when there is no user input?

Some time ago I ran into this problem, I was doing some kind of block on input thing and my game was just running when I pressed a key, lol.

Comment: This can be solved with a 60hz timer, but that often introduces more overhead than simply polling, as you already have the constant 60hz.